# Lighty netconf implementation using spring boot application

Tags: java, opendaylight, ietf-netconf, ietf-restconf, lighty

I am creating client application for netconf devices. I am using lighty.io package to implement. Here in this code i am using spring-boot application to test.

I am only able to connect to Toster device not other device why is this so. I want make such a client application which will get connected to all the netconf devices.